# How to return a table that removed SQL rows that match two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table that returns some rows, what we are looking at is only if rxID matches and also if those amountPaid is opposite of eachother.

In the screenshot, we have two entries of an rxID of 3350593 that has an amount paid of 2.35 and -2.35. That is in a money type format.

My query so far, only returns those two rows[image] because it is matching on rxId. y.amountpaid at the bottom, cannot be found, and t.amountpaid cannot be just selected while also grouping by t.rxid.

If I can get a query to remove those two rows that have the same rxID and inversed amount paids, I'd appreciative.

```
 SELECT x.*
  FROM 
(
 SELECT IsInstyRxFlag,   pri.payerReceiptItemId,   CONVERT(varchar,rx.oeDate, 101) rxOeDate,  CONVERT(DECIMAL(6,2), drx.payerOblig) payerObligation,    CONVERT(DECIMAL(6,2), pri.amountPaid) amountPaid,  pri.rxId,    CONVERT(DECIMAL(6,2), (pri.amountPaid - drx.payerOblig)) difference, rxeventid  
 FROM PayerReceiptItem pri 
 JOIN Rx ON rx.rxId = pri.rxId 
  JOIN DispenseRx drx ON rx.rxId = drx.rxId  
  WHERE CONVERT(DECIMAL(6,2), drx.payerOblig) <>  CONVERT(DECIMAL(6,2), pri.amountPaid)      AND payerReceiptID = 19781
  ) x
 JOIN (SELECT t.rxID
      FROM
       (
   SELECT IsInstyRxFlag,   pri.payerReceiptItemId,           CONVERT(varchar,rx.oeDate, 101) rxOeDate,  CONVERT(DECIMAL(6,2), drx.payerOblig) payerObligation,    CONVERT(DECIMAL(6,2), pri.amountPaid) amountPaid,  pri.rxId,    CONVERT(DECIMAL(6,2), (pri.amountPaid - drx.payerOblig)) difference, rxeventid  
   FROM PayerReceiptItem pri 
  JOIN Rx ON rx.rxId = pri.rxId 
 JOIN DispenseRx drx ON rx.rxId = drx.rxId  
  WHERE CONVERT(DECIMAL(6,2), drx.payerOblig) <>  CONVERT(DECIMAL(6,2), pri.amountPaid)      AND payerReceiptID = 19781
 ) t

  GROUP BY t.rxID
     HAVING COUNT(t.rxID) > 1) y ON  y.rxID = x.rxid

     --can't find y.amountpaid, x can be seen
     --and y.amountPaid = x.amountPaid
```

Now working with this, but x.amount paid is invalid because it is not an aggregate function.

```
with 
x AS (SELECT IsInstyRxFlag
, pri.payerReceiptItemId
, CONVERT(varchar,rx.oeDate, 101) rxOeDate
, CONVERT(DECIMAL(6,2), drx.payerOblig) payerObligation
, CONVERT(DECIMAL(6,2), pri.amountPaid) amountPaid
, pri.rxId
, CONVERT(DECIMAL(6,2), (pri.amountPaid - drx.payerOblig)) difference
, rxeventid  
FROM PayerReceiptItem pri 
 JOIN Rx ON rx.rxId = pri.rxId 
JOIN DispenseRx drx ON rx.rxId = drx.rxId  
WHERE CONVERT(DECIMAL(6,2), drx.payerOblig) <>  CONVERT(DECIMAL(6,2), pri.amountPaid) AND payerReceiptID = 19781)
SELECT x.*
 FROM x


   where not exists(
   SELECT * 
    FROM x AS y
    WHERE x.amountpaid = -1* y.amountpaid
  AND x.difference = x.amountpaid 
  AND x.rxid = y.rxid 
   );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What result you expect? I simplify your query, look at this:

```
with 
  x AS (SELECT IsInstyRxFlag
  , pri.payerReceiptItemId
  , CONVERT(varchar,rx.oeDate, 101) rxOeDate
  , CONVERT(DECIMAL(6,2), drx.payerOblig) payerObligation
  , CONVERT(DECIMAL(6,2), pri.amountPaid) amountPaid
  , pri.rxId
  , CONVERT(DECIMAL(6,2), (pri.amountPaid - drx.payerOblig)) difference
  , rxeventid  
  FROM PayerReceiptItem pri 
  JOIN Rx ON rx.rxId = pri.rxId 
  JOIN DispenseRx drx ON rx.rxId = drx.rxId  
  WHERE CONVERT(DECIMAL(6,2), drx.payerOblig) <>  CONVERT(DECIMAL(6,2), pri.amountPaid) AND payerReceiptID = 19781)
SELECT x.*
FROM x
JOIN (
  SELECT t.rxID -- how you want to find amountpaid if you don't select this
  --you can select max or min from amountpaid, to not group by this field
  , min(amountpaid) min_amountpaid, max(amountpaid) max_amountpaid
  FROM x t
  GROUP BY t.rxID
  HAVING COUNT(t.rxID) > 1) y 
ON  y.rxID = x.rxid
```

**EDIT:**
but if you only need exclude this two rows, try this query:

```
with 
  x AS (SELECT IsInstyRxFlag
  , pri.payerReceiptItemId
  , CONVERT(varchar,rx.oeDate, 101) rxOeDate
  , CONVERT(DECIMAL(6,2), drx.payerOblig) payerObligation
  , CONVERT(DECIMAL(6,2), pri.amountPaid) amountPaid
  , pri.rxId
  , CONVERT(DECIMAL(6,2), (pri.amountPaid - drx.payerOblig)) difference
  , rxeventid  
  FROM PayerReceiptItem pri 
  JOIN Rx ON rx.rxId = pri.rxId 
  JOIN DispenseRx drx ON rx.rxId = drx.rxId  
  WHERE CONVERT(DECIMAL(6,2), drx.payerOblig) <>  CONVERT(DECIMAL(6,2), pri.amountPaid) AND payerReceiptID = 19781)
SELECT x.*
FROM x
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM x t WHERE t.rxID = x.rxID and t.amountPaid = -1 * x.amountPaid )
```

Comment: I need the query to remove the two rows that match RXID and have amountPaid of 2.35 = -2.35...  GROUP BY t.rxID
         HAVING COUNT(t.rxID) > 1) y ON  y.rxID != x.rxid and y.amountpaid = x.amountpaid * -1

Comment: but y.amount paid only has Count(t.rxid), and t.amountpaid only has t.rxid.

Comment: To clarify, if the y.rxid = x.rxid is true, we have two matches, the amountPaid could be 0, and 1. Thats not equal, we need to keep that.

Comment: I edited my main post, I just added an extra thing at the end.

Comment: so, you need exclude this two rows? if yes, you don't need join, use exists to build condition: if not exist row that have same rxID and negative amountPaid

Comment: Yes, I need to exclude the rows on rxid and compare amount paid. I'll try and figure it out. Thanks for telling me to use exists.

Comment: you can also group by x columns without amountPaid, select grouped fields and sum(amountPaid) and add condition `HAVING Sum(amountPaid ) <>0`

Comment: I did it! Thanks a lot! :) :) :), what i used is above